# In Google Sheets is it possible to have a drop down change other drop downs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

I am unsure of how to ask what I am looking for in simple terms.

But in Google Sheets I am trying to get a data validation range from a database sheet to change a set of other data validation ranges you can select from and if you cannot use data validation is there a formula that can replace this action and or something similar using script editor to display information as a drop down.

Example:
You have a drop-down which has a list of countries.

Then a second list which changes the states you can select depending which country you selected previously.

Comment: You should try somthing with [VLookUp function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en), passing selected country as an argument. _VLookUp_ will always return the 1st value found, so you will need to change the area of the search table according to the cell you're currently in.

Comment: @Vincent `VLookUp will always return the 1st value found` - that's not correct; it will only if the "if_sorted" attribute = TRUE. While this is the default value, users might be confused because the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) recommends "FALSE" in most cases.

Comment: see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-I8Z4nTDak

Comment: It is also possible to implement it with an Apps Script, but it implies that you have some experience with it.